# A formula for the Jacobian of a flow

Tags: reference-request, differential-equations, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $U : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ be a smooth vector field, and let $F_t : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ be the corresponding smooth flow, defined by the differential equation $$\tfrac{d}{dt} F_t(x) = U(F_t(x)).$$  Let $f : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be an integrable function, and consider the integral $$\int_{\mathbb R^d} f( F_t(x) ) ~dx.$$  To calculate this, I would make the change of variables $y = F_t(x)$, making the ansatz that there exists some function $\rho(y)$ so that the integral equals $$\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(y) \rho(y) ~dy.$$  From what I can gather from [the paper I'm reading](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1428307), it's common knowledge that this function $\rho$ has the form $$\rho(y) = \tfrac{1}{J_t(F_t^{-1}(y))} = \exp \left(-\int_0^t (\operatorname{div} U)(F_{s-t}(y) ) ~ds \right),$$ where of course $J_t$ stands for the Jacobian of the flow.

Could you please point me to a reference for this formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [the Liouville formula](http://eom.springer.de/l/l059660.htm). It is explained nicely in *Ordinary Differential Equations* by Arnold.

Comment: Bravo, I knew it would be simple.  Thanks, Andrey.

Comment: For future finders of this question:  the precise location Section 27.6 (Liouville's Theorem) on page 195 of Arnold's Ordinary Differential Equations (the green book, translated by Richard Silverman, not the yellow one translated by Cooke).

Comment: The link to `eom.springer.de` is broken, but the article can now be found at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Liouville-Ostrogradski_formula.

Comment: I think it is only for linear systems...